# Why doesn't eventlet GreenPool call func after spawn_n unless waitall()?

Tags: python, eventlet, green-threads

This code prints nothing:

```
def foo(i):
    print i

def main():
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool(size=100)
    for i in xrange(100):
        pool.spawn_n(foo, i)
    while True:
        pass
```

But this code prints numbers:

```
def foo(i):
    print i

def main():
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool(size=100)
    for i in xrange(100):
        pool.spawn_n(foo, i)
    pool.waitall()
    while True:
        pass
```

The only difference is `pool.waitall()`. In my mind, `waitall()` means wait until all greenthreads in the pool are finished working, but an infinite loop waits for every greenthread, so `pool.waitall()` is not necessary.

So why does this happen?

Reference: http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/greenpool.html#eventlet.greenpool.GreenPool.waitall

Answer (score 6):

The threads created in an eventlet `GreenPool` are *green threads*. This means that they all exist within one thread at the operating-system level, and the Python interpreter handles switching between them. This switching can only happen when one thread either *yields* (deliberately provides an opportunity for other threads to run) or is waiting for I/O.

When your code runs:

```
while True:
    pass
```

… that thread of execution is *blocked* – stuck on that code – and no other green threads can get scheduled.

When you instead run:

```
pool.waitall()
```

… eventlet makes sure that it yields while waiting.

You could emulate this same behaviour by modifying your `while` loop slightly to call the `eventlet.sleep` function, which yields:

```
while True:
    eventlet.sleep()
```

This could be useful if you wanted to do something else in the `while True:` loop while waiting for the threads in your pool to complete. Otherwise, just use `pool.waitall()` – that’s what it’s for.